# What is DLL Import attribute?

Tags: c#

```
using System;
System.Runtime.InteropServices;
class Beeper
{
      DllImport("kernel32.dll")]//low level beep
      public static extern bool Beep(int frequency,int duration);
      static void Main()
      {
         Beep(1000,111);
      }
}
```

What is DLL Import Attribute, what does it do exactly?

Comment: [MSDN DllImportAttribute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.interopservices.dllimportattribute.aspx)

Comment: You can't just change the body of a question entirely after people have answered, commented, and voted. None of the earlier content makes any sense now. If you want to ask another question, create a new one, please.

Comment: The downvotes are not because you are new to programming, it's because you are using StackOverflow incorrectly. For example you have posted a comment by editing the body of your question. That's what comments are for. Also, I second peachykeen's argument. Roll back the question to its original form. Question edits are for clarifying questions.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because the answer is available in the official documentation.

Answer (score 3):

It’s a string like any other specifying the name of the DLL. You need to quote it.

```
[DllImport("kernel32.dll")]
```

Also, this:

```
System.Runtime.InteropServices.DllImportAttribute;
```

should be:

```
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
```

And why not just use `Console.Beep`?

---

Anyways, the [`System.Runtime.InteropServices.DllImport` attribute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.interopservices.dllimportattribute.aspx) is an attribute you can put on empty (`extern`) methods to make them reference a method with that signature in the referenced DLL.

Comment: You cleared compile time errors. but failed to explain the question

Comment: +1 for the `Console.Beep` suggestion - almost always better to just use the framework versions